# Weird problem with entering numpad keystrokes in JTextComponent

Tags: java, swing, vnc, jdk1.4, sco-unix

I'm using SCO OSR5 Operating system.
My java version is 1.4

I have a really weird problem, with entering numpad keystrokes in JTextComponent.

When I'm using VNC connection everything works fine. When I review the keycodes that VNC sends with "xev" command, they are correct. For instance `KP_5` button sends `0xffb5`. All JTextComponent action events are fired properly.

But when I'm using local X server and press numpad 5 button in JTextComponent it fails, no action events are fired at all. Test with "xev" shows that X keyboard driver also sends `0xffb5` for `KP_5`, but this time JVM doesn't reacts at all.

Any ideas? Does anybody expirienced simillar problems?

Comment: Why are you using an ancient jvm?

Comment: That is all you can get in SCO OSR5

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest Java at:

http://www.sco.com/support/update/download/release.php?rid=377